# NSTextField GotFocus Event Cocoa Swift

Tags: cocoa, swift, events, focus, nstextfield

In swift Cocoa is there an event that fires when a NSTextField gets focus for editing. I Come from C# which has GotFocus() and LostFocus() Events.

For NSTextfield I could find only these functions which fire after one starts typing. Not as soon as focus is gained.

```
 override func controlTextDidBeginEditing(obj: NSNotification) {
 }

 func control(control: NSControl, textShouldBeginEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool {

 }
```

I Need this because as soon as someone starts editing, I want to show more detail. I have a simpler display name, and full name for editing.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subclass NSTextField and override becomeFirstResponder and resignFirstResponder. Please check this link [How to detect when NSTextField has the focus or is it's content selected cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692122/how-to-detect-when-nstextfield-has-the-focus-or-is-its-content-selected-cocoa)

Comment: Please Check Ur Spelling NSTextfield  "UITextfield"

Comment: @Abhay, NSTextField is in Cocoa and UITextField in UIKit. It is not a spelling mistake

Comment: If you're going to use ``becomeFirstResponder`` and ``resignFirstResponder`` it'll also be worth your while to become familiar with the operation of the window's ``fieldEditor``. This object (an ``NSTextView`` subclass) is where you're editing *actually* happens and it's worth knowing about because when you think your ``NSTextField`` has focus, it doesn't - the field editor does. Appreciating this help you understand why you're ``NSTextField`` is *not* the first responder even when you're happily typing text into it.

Comment: Excellent!. I had to call a custom delegate from inside overriding the become first responder then listen for that "event".